# Trying to access xml file in tomcat via URL, getting 404 error

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I have a webapp deployed in Tomee+ 1.6.0 (tomcat 7.0). The app runs fine and I can access all pages. Within one of my app's folders (myapp/intructions/) I have placed a xml file that I will access via a client application.

The application will access the file for its configuration, and will be called via a batch file with the following command:

```
"C:\Java\jre7\bin\java" -cp MyApp.jar com.me.MyApplicationStart "argument1" "argument2"
```

Within MyApplicationStart the constructor tries to access the configuration from the URL

```
http://webserver:8080/myapp/instruction/myconfig.xml
```

As I have no control over the above methodology, this cannot be changed.

I would expect the xml to be downloaded (or fetched) and my application to work fine, but instead I get a 404 error. If I change the extension of my config file to .properties, everything works fine, but someone else other than me in the team insists that we use xml for the config file, since it will allow more automation features.

What gets me is why can't I access this xml (or any other) file from tomcat. It seems that in previous versions of tomcat this was not a problem, or at least not with files outside the WEB-INF folder. Now it is and it seems to be exclusive to xml files, which suggests that there's a configuration in place that prevents access to this extension from anywhere in the webapp.

Would anybody know what this configuration is, or what is the mechanics behind this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file render in browser?. I tested Tomcat 7 my dropping in a random XML file at the root of my application and it renders correctly. I tried this with the Tomcat examples app as well like http://localhost:8080/examples/myfile.xml

Comment: No, that's what I am trying to get, but it's giving me a 404. If I choose another extension such as properties it renders fine... that's why I am puzzled. I would imagine there's a setting that causes this issue, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you try what i did - use the same myconfig.xml in another app like 'docs' or 'examples'

Comment: I did and it works, so it seems to be exclusive to my app. It's a legacy app, so nothing much I know about it...

Comment: Check your web.xml for any security-constraint on .xml url-pattern

Comment: Got it. Indeed I found an exception pattern to avoid people from executing xmls from urls. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for security reason, WEB-INF folder is not accessible from client side.

put your xml file in other location.

and try again, It will work